# How do i add javascript in TCPDF?

Tags: javascript, php, tcpdf

As i can't use css to make my auto numbering for my tables with css using TCPDF.I'm trying to use Javascipt to make this work. I read the documentation([this](https://tcpdf.org/examples/example_053/) and [this](https://tcpdf.org/examples/example_014/)) on how to add javascript into my tcpdf. But i do not know why it does not work and it shows the error of `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'var' (T_VAR) in C:\filepath\XAMPP\htdocs\filepath\customerinvoice.php on line 211` Can i know how can i define my 'var' in tcpdf? Or is not possible to add javascript in TCPDF? Please help me with this issue. Any help will be apprecialted. Thanks in advance

This are my codes

```
    $htmlcontent .='
<table cellpadding="7" style="max-height: 1000px;">
    <tr class="receiptcontent">
    <td style="font-weight: normal;font-size: 12px;line-height: 17px;color: #000000;">

    </td>

        <td width= "30%" colspan="3" style="font-weight: normal;font-size: 12px;line-height: 17px;color: #000000;">
            '.$irow['product_name'].'
        </td>
        
         <td style=" font-weight: normal;font-size: 12px;line-height: 17px;color: #000000;">
           '.$irow['product_code'].'
        </td>
         <td width= "15%" style=" font-weight: normal;font-size: 12px;line-height: 17px;color: #000000;">
           '.$irow['quantity'].' '.$irow['quantity_unit'].'
        </td>
         <td  width= "15%" style=" font-weight: normal;font-size: 12px;line-height: 17px;color: #000000;">
          RM '.$irow['original_price'].'
        </td>
        <td  width= "20%" style=" font-weight: normal;font-size: 12px;line-height: 17px;color: #000000;">
            RM '.$irow['price'].'
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

';
}
```

This is the javascript i added in to implement auto numbering for my tables

```
$js = 
var table = document.getElementsByTagName('table')[0],
  rows = table.getElementsByTagName('tr'),
  text = 'textContent' in document ? 'textContent' : 'innerText';

for (var i = 0, len = rows.length; i < len; i++) {
  rows[i].children[0][text] = i + ': ' + rows[i].children[0][text];
};
    
// Add Javascript code
$pdf->IncludeJS($js);
    $pdf->writeHTML($htmlcontent);  
    ob_end_clean(); 
    $pdf->Output('customerinvoice.pdf', 'I');
```

Answer (score 0):

Please enclose the js statements in double quotations:

Change

```
$js = 
var table = document.getElementsByTagName('table')[0],
  rows = table.getElementsByTagName('tr'),
  text = 'textContent' in document ? 'textContent' : 'innerText';

for (var i = 0, len = rows.length; i < len; i++) {
  rows[i].children[0][text] = i + ': ' + rows[i].children[0][text];
};
```

to

```
$js =" 
var table = document.getElementsByTagName('table')[0],
  rows = table.getElementsByTagName('tr'),
  text = 'textContent' in document ? 'textContent' : 'innerText';

for (var i = 0, len = rows.length; i < len; i++) {
  rows[i].children[0][text] = i + ': ' + rows[i].children[0][text];
};
"
```

Comment: i added the double quotations. Can i know why the javascript is still not functioning? I tried my javascript code in regular html it is working perfectly but idk why it does not work on the TCPDF

Comment: also why do i need to add double quotation for that? the examples in the documentation does not have double quotation in the javascript code

Comment: When you add javascript (JS) to TCPDF (which is in PHP), you need to enclose the JS as string, otherwise the system will throw an error. The example you are using make sure of `<<<EOD` and `EOD;` , which are for a similar purpose.

Comment: If your JS is still not working, then please check the syntax and the context.

Comment: I checked, but there's no mistake in my syntax and the context. Is it i can't add javascript in tcpdf?

Comment: TCPDF for sure supports javascript. But you need to make sure that the javascript codes is still "AVAILABLE" for execution. For your codes, it appears that you want to process thru `getElementsByTagName` on a `table` , but the `table` might not exist in your finally generated pdf file, because I believe you have used TCPDF to generate the contents into the PDF file which is embedded in the PDF and not available for execution.